# Using Google Visualization: Organizational Chart offline

Tags: google-visualization, offline-mode

Can i use [Google Visualization: Organizational Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart) in offline mode ?

Comment: You Can do a work around, but I can't/won't tell you for legal issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly is not possible to use google charts offline.

Read the FAQ for more information:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq?hl=it#offline

Answer (score 0):

save https://www.google.com/jsapi as a my.js file(copy-paste with some text editor) on the same folder as your html and replace

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
```

with

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='my.js'></script>
```

Comment: I try to do this, but i get blank chart

Comment: blank chart either you're online or offline?

Comment: i got an blank chart in offline mode

Comment: Look at the jsapi file. Every graph uses more than 1 file. For barchart I see 4 files at network history of my Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

This would not work 
first Google do not permit this
secondly if you copy paste it would not work
as jsapi file generates a file like google/udc/?vi.... referencing locally will not work if you 
add `<script type='text/javascript' src='my.js'></script>` it will generate file my.js/?vi....'
and it would not load (404 Not Found) if you remove .js extention

Answer (score 0):

I't not possible to use google charts offline. Legaly impossible.

I made an organizational chart using Jit js, and you can use it offline.

https://github.com/rlopez0689/OrgChartJit